# Python Azure function used in Data Factory returns: "Response Content is not a valid JObject"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have created a very basic HTTP Trigger in Python that I can validate and test with success. However when I plug it in Data Factory and no matter what I do I get the message:

> Response Content is not a valid JObject

From the Azure Python function I tried returning:

> return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(f"Hello Test!"), mimetype='application/json')

and also:

> return json.dumps(f"Hello Test!")

But in both cases I always get the not valid JObject error message. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write it with a mistake of "f"

return json.dumps(**f**"Hello Test!")

And could you please try to modify your code to

```
a = {'name': 'wang'}
json.dumps(a)
```